# HTML parsing with VB.Net

Tags: html, vb.net, parsing

Does anybody know of a good way of parsing HTML in VB.Net.

I found a solution somewhere on the net using MSHTML.

I tried using it and to get it to work I had to add some code to my project:

```
Public Enum HRESULT
    S_OK = 0
    S_FALSE = 1
    E_NOTIMPL = &H80004001
    E_INVALIDARG = &H80070057
    E_NOINTERFACE = &H80004002
    E_FAIL = &H80004005
    E_UNEXPECTED = &H8000FFFF
End Enum

<ComVisible(True), ComImport(), Guid("7FD52380-4E07-101B-AE2D-08002B2EC713"), _
    InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)> _
Public Interface IPersistStreamInit : Inherits IPersist
    Shadows Sub GetClassID(ByRef pClassID As Guid)
    <PreserveSig()> Function IsDirty() As Integer
    <PreserveSig()> Function Load(ByVal pstm As UCOMIStream) As HRESULT
    <PreserveSig()> Function Save(ByVal pstm As UCOMIStream, _
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal fClearDirty As Boolean) As HRESULT
    <PreserveSig()> Function GetSizeMax(<InAttribute(), Out(), _
    MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)> ByRef pcbSize As Long) As HRESULT
    <PreserveSig()> Function InitNew() As HRESULT
End Interface

<ComVisible(True), ComImport(), Guid("0000010c-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), _
    InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)> _
Public Interface IPersist
    Sub GetClassID(ByRef pClassID As Guid)
End Interface

Declare Function CreateStreamOnHGlobal Lib "ole32" (ByVal hGlobal As IntPtr, ByVal fDeleteOnRelease As Boolean, _
    ByRef ppstm As UCOMIStream) As Long
' Please note that i copied above IPersistStream definition from sp!ke. I owe him a drink ;).
```

End Class

And now I'm getting obsolete warnings:

```
Warning 1   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.UCOMIStream' is obsolete: 'Use System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream instead. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202'.
```

I didn't like the fact that I had to use the MSHTML stuff (cause I think IE uses it also, and we all know that IE sucks :) ) and that I had to add code the make it work.

Don't want to start a browser-war thread so neglect my last remark. :)

Is there a different (/better) approach of parsing html-pages in VB.Net.

Basically what I'm trying to do is get all the links (`<a>` tags) and embeds (`<object>` tag) on a page.

Thanks in advance for all you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

use

Html Agility Pack. Its best one out there. It can be done without browser.

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

In WinForm App, you can create an object of WebBrowser and let it load page, then you can find any tag name and data by dom node.